# Is it possible for d_ptr to be NULL when Object is valid and alive?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class MyAction which derives from the `QWidgetAction` which derives from the `QAction`.
When I call `QWidget::addActions(QList<QAction*> actions)`, I have exception on trying to get `d_ptr` and use it (inside `QWidget`, not by myself) from action in list:

```
QActionPrivate *apriv = action->d_func();
apriv->widgets.append(this);
```

Code above is taken from QWidget source file. By the way, my action is placed in actions list as cast of `this` pointer which of type MyAction:

```
actions->push_back(this);
```

I think that the reason of exception in that that I trying to push into QList my class MyAction, casting `const this` pointer to `QAction*`.

Comment: You should not be using `d_ptr`, it is not part of the API and could change without notice (although improbable) in future versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in that I created MyAction variable on the stack, so, actually, QObject wasn't alive when I'm trying to pass it to QWidget function. That's why I couldn't get d-pointer different from NULL. I couldn't knew that object was actually dead, all strings and variables inside my action was valid.

Comment: So much for not providing an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) test case? By the way, have you read my answer. Just do not use dptr from client code.

Comment: I didn't use dptr even a single time and wrote about that. SSCCE is not only a short code implementation. In this situation, when I have to implement several functions and class for example of usage, just text explanation is shorter.

Comment: Do you seriously think when you use d func you do not utilize the d_ptr?

Comment: This code is a part of qwidget.h. I don't use d-func at all. If you want to say that I'm bad at composing good questions, so, you already did.

Answer (score 0):

If [d-pointer](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Dpointer) pattern is used properly then it never can be null.
D-pointer have to point to valid memory block which will live as long as object lives.

Only exception for this role are classes implementing copy on write which provide null state (for example QString), but this never applies to `QObjects`.

Your problem must be result of some dangling pointer or other memory issue. Or incorrect type casting. In such cases call stack doesn't have to point to source of problem, problem can be almost anywhere.

I recommend to run your program with valgrind or other memory checking tool. Or some static analysis tool.

Comment: Yep, seems like wrong pointer casting and I have only one place where pointer casts. But that thing works for many other places. So, what I can do to pass `this` as `QAction` in constructor in correct way? Also, I trying this thing in Qt Creator with simple example and it works.

Comment: your main question is incomplete and your comment brings more question what are you exactly doing? Never Ever use private stuff from external library (qt in this case), when you do that you are taking a risk that different version of library (qt) will cause problems (crash). Maybe you should explain why you invade internal implementation of qt.

Comment: Hmm. I never used d-pointer, the exception throws inside QWidget method. All I want is to add my action to widget.

Comment: looks like we are not on the same page. When you wrote "I have exception on trying to get d_ptr from action in list:" I assumed that this is YOUR code. If you do not touch d pointers then it is Ok, but you should read my answer again, I've wrote: "Your problem must be result of some dangling pointer or other memory issue ... In such cases call stack doesn't have to point to source of problem, problem can be almost anywhere."

Comment: Memory issue like memory/heap corruption? If so, I don't think that it's possible.

Comment: Like I wrote use valgrind or similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `d_func()` from client code. The whole point of the [pimpl idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29) is to stay away from the implementation details and that the library can freely change implementation details like data representation, internal methods and so on.

That is, d_func() along with d_ptr is meant for internal usage. If you need to access it for some reason, that means you seem to violate the design principle of the library, or you are trying to access something that should be exposed to the API, but was not yet needed.

Based on your exact use case - which we do not know, I would suggest to consider these alternatives.